# Rewrite rule in htaccess on wamp server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wamp

I'm trying to rewrite my url in a project in wamp service but can't get it working.

I want to rewrite based on these two rules basically

FROM:

- localhost/project/modulos/tags/edit/3

TO:

- localhost/project/modulos/tags/index.php?action=edit&id=3

AND
FROM:

- localhost/project/modulos/tags/lis

TO:

- localhost/project/modulos/tags/index.php?action=list

My htaccess is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^modulos\/(.*)\/(.*)$ index.php?action=%1&id%2
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: if you don't want to rewrite URL, you can remove htaccess file or delete the rewrite code in htaccess file

Comment: starkeen,  It just don't do anything. Raj_King, I want to rewrite my URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `%1` and `%2` instead, they should be `$1` and `$2` respectively. Putting more specific rules first:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase modulos/
RewriteRule ^modulos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/index.php?action=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^modulos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/index.php?action=$2 [L]
```